# How do I pass my value in root of css in reactjs?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

I have a problem wherein I can't pass my value of "seconds" for the animation...
Supposingly I have something like this in my css

```
:root {
  --speed: 1s;
}

animation: rotate var(--speed) ease-in-out infinite;
```

And that I want to pass my inputs in reactjs so that it will change the `value of duration`

```
const handleChangeRevolution = e => {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--speed",e.target.value)
}
```

I did something like this wherein I input my numbers for duration of the speed

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  name="revolve" 
  value={revolve} 
  onChange={e => handleChangeRevolution(e)} />
```

Any idea guys? I don't wanna change the code here...I just wanna fix the problem how to pass it. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, thank you guys. I just need to add the `'s'` I forgot.

```
const handleChangeRevolution = e => {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--speed", e.target.value + 's')
}
```